# Strange Template error : error C2783: could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have created a simple function with 2 diffrernt template arguments t1, t2 and return type t3.
So far no compilation error. But when Itry to call the function from main, I encounter error C2783. 
I needed to know If the following code is legally ok? If not how is it fixed?
please help!

```
template <typename t1, typename t2, typename t3> 
t3 adder1 (t1  a , t2 b)
    {
        return int(a + b);
    };


int main()
{
       int sum = adder1(1,6.0);  // error C2783 could not deduce template argument for t3
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way for the compiler to deduce `t3` from the function arguments. You need to pass this argument explicitly. Change the order of the parameters to make this possible

```
template <typename t3, typename t1, typename t2> 
t3 adder1 (t1  a , t2 b)
    {
        return t3(a + b); // use t3 instead of fixed "int" here!
    };
```

Then you can call it with `adder1<int>(1, 6.0)`. It's more difficult if you want to deduce `t3` to the actual result of the addition. C++0x (next C++ version's codename) will allow to do this by saying that the return type is equal to the type of the addition the following way

```
template <typename t1, typename t2> 
auto adder1 (t1  a , t2 b) -> decltype(a+b)
    {
        return a + b;
    };
```

Then you could cast explictly at the point of use

```
int sum = (int) adder1(1,6.0); // cast from double to int
```

Simulate this in the current C++ version isn't going to be easy. You can use my [promote template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426330/uses-of-a-c-arithmetic-promotion-header/2450157#2450157) to do that. If you feel that this rather confuses the matter for you and that you are OK with explictly providing the return type, i think it's better to stay with explicitly providing it. Like [Herb Sutter says](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/advice97.htm) "Write What You Know, and Know What You Write"

Nontheless you can do the above like this with that template

```
template <typename t1, typename t2> 
typename promote<t1, t2>::type adder1 (t1 a, t2 b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

When attempting to deduce the template type, the compiler is not going to look at the actual *code* of the function. If you know the return type will be `int`, then make it `int`.

```
template <typename t1, typename t2> 
int adder1 (t1  a , t2 b)
{
    return int(a + b);
};


int main()
{
   int sum = adder1(1,6.0);  // error C2783 could not deduce template argument for t3
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the only way to call your function would be `adder1<int, double, int>(...)`.

You could make your function return an explicit `t3` argument or pass this argument by a reference, like

```
adder(const t1& a, const t2&b, t3& result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always returning an `int` hence t3 is not required. You can modify your code as:

```
template <typename t1, typename t2> 
int adder1 (t1  a , t2 b)
    {
        return int(a + b);
    };


int main()
{

       int sum = adder1(1,6.0);  // error C2783 could not deduce template argument for t3
       return 0;

}
```