# I have a program that works for whole numbers, but I need to get it to work for decimal numbers as well

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

So my assignment requires us to use doubly linked lists to add or multiply numbers together and print them out. I was able to get it to work for whole numbers, but I can't figure out what to change to make it work for decimal numbers as well. Here's what I've got so far. I know it's not the most efficient or cleanest code, but I can try to clarify stuff if it doesn't make sense to you
For example this program will work fine if I do 50382+9281 or 482891*29734,but I need to get it to work for something like 4.9171+49.2917 or 423.135*59

EDIT: Pretend the int values are doubles. I changed it on my actual code, but the result when I do the math is still giving me a whole number so I need to figure out how to insert the decimal at the right place

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
// A recursive program to add two linked lists
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// A linked List Node
struct node
{
    int data;
     node* next;
    node *prev;
};

typedef struct node node;

class LinkedList{


    // public member
public:
    // constructor
    LinkedList(){
        int length = 0;
        head = NULL; // set head to NULL

        node *n = new node;
        n->data = -1;
        n->prev = NULL;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }

    // This prepends a new value at the beginning of the list
    void addValue(int val){
        node *n = new node();   // create new Node
        n->data = val;             // set value
        n->prev = tail;         // make the node point to the next node.

     //   head->next = n;
     //   head = n;
    //    tail->next = n;                        //  If the list is empty, this is NULL, so the end of the list --> OK
        tail = n;               // last but not least, make the head point at the new node.
    }

    void PrintForward(){
        node* temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            cout << temp->data;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    void PrintReverse(){
        node* temp = tail;
        while(temp->prev != NULL){
            cout << temp->data;
            temp = temp->prev;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }

    void PrintReverse(node* in){
        node* temp = in;
        if(temp->prev== NULL){
                if(temp->data == -1)
            cout << temp->data << '\n';
            }
        else{
            cout << temp->data << '\n';
            temp = temp->prev;
            PrintReverse(temp);

            }
    }
    // returns the first element in the list and deletes the Node.
    // caution, no error-checking here!
    int popValue(){
        node *n = head;
        int ret = n->data;

        head = head->next;
        delete n;
        return ret;
    }

    void swapN(node** a, node**b){
        node*t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
    }


        node *head;
        node *tail;
       // Node *n;
};

/* A utility function to insert a node at the beginning of linked list */
    void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
    {
        /* allocate node */
        struct node* new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        /* put in the data  */
        new_node->data  = new_data;

        /* link the old list off the new node */
        new_node->next = (*head_ref);

        /* move the head to point to the new node */
        (*head_ref)    = new_node;
    }

/* A utility function to print linked list */
    void printList(struct node *node)
    {
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", node->data);
            node = node->next;
        }
     //   printf("\n");
    }

// A utility function to swap two pointers
    void swapPointer( node** a, node** b )
    {
        node* t = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = t;
    }

/* A utility function to get size of linked list */
    int getSize(struct node *node)
    {
        int size = 0;
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            node = node->next;
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

// Adds two linked lists of same size represented by head1 and head2 and returns
// head of the resultant linked list. Carry is propagated while returning from
// the recursion
    node* addSameSize(node* head1, node* head2, int* carry)
    {
        // Since the function assumes linked lists are of same size,
        // check any of the two head pointers
        if (head1 == NULL)
            return NULL;

        int sum;

        // Allocate memory for sum node of current two nodes
        node* result = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

        // Recursively add remaining nodes and get the carry
        result->next = addSameSize(head1->next, head2->next, carry);

        // add digits of current nodes and propagated carry
        sum = head1->data + head2->data + *carry;
        *carry = sum / 10;
        sum = sum % 10;

        // Assigne the sum to current node of resultant list
        result->data = sum;

        return result;
    }

// This function is called after the smaller list is added to the bigger
// lists's sublist of same size.  Once the right sublist is added, the carry
// must be added toe left side of larger list to get the final result.
    void addCarryToRemaining(node* head1, node* cur, int* carry, node** result)
    {
        int sum;

        // If diff. number of nodes are not traversed, add carry
        if (head1 != cur)
        {
            addCarryToRemaining(head1->next, cur, carry, result);

            sum = head1->data + *carry;
            *carry = sum/10;
            sum %= 10;

            // add this node to the front of the result
            push(result, sum);
        }
    }

// The main function that adds two linked lists represented by head1 and head2.
// The sum of two lists is stored in a list referred by result
    void addList(node* head1, node* head2, node** result)
    {
        node *cur;

        // first list is empty
        if (head1 == NULL)
        {
            *result = head2;
            return;
        }

        // second list is empty
        else if (head2 == NULL)
        {
            *result = head1;
            return;
        }

        int size1 = getSize(head1);
        int size2 = getSize(head2) ;

        int carry = 0;

        // Add same size lists
        if (size1 == size2)
            *result = addSameSize(head1, head2, &carry);

        else
        {
            int diff = abs(size1 - size2);

            // First list should always be larger than second list.
            // If not, swap pointers
            if (size1 < size2)
                swapPointer(&head1, &head2);

            // move diff. number of nodes in first list
            for (cur = head1; diff--; cur = cur->next);

            // get addition of same size lists
            *result = addSameSize(cur, head2, &carry);

            // get addition of remaining first list and carry
            addCarryToRemaining(head1, cur, &carry, result);
        }

        // if some carry is still there, add a new node to the fron of
        // the result list. e.g. 999 and 87
        if (carry)
            push(result, carry);
    }

        node* reverse_list(node *m)
        {
            node *next = NULL;
            node *p = m;
            node *prev;

            while (p != NULL) {
                prev = p->prev;
                p->prev = next;
                next = p;
                p = prev;
            }

            return prev;
        }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            void Multiply2(node* n1, node* n2);
            int digitsPerNode = 2;
            node* result;
            node* resultp = result;
            node* resultp2 = result;
            void Multiply(node* n1, node* n2)
            {
                if (n2->prev != NULL)
                {
                    Multiply(n1, n2->prev);
                }

                Multiply2(n1, n2);
                resultp2 = resultp = resultp->prev;
            }

         void Multiply2(node* n1, node* n2)
            {
                if (n1->prev != NULL)
                {
                    Multiply2(n1->prev, n2);
                }

                if (resultp2 == NULL)
                {
                    resultp2->data = 0;
                    result = resultp = resultp2;
                }

                int m = n1->data * n2->data + resultp2->data;

                int carryon = (int)(m / pow(10, digitsPerNode));
                resultp2->data = m % (int)pow(10, digitsPerNode);
                if (carryon > 0)
                {
                    if (resultp2->prev == NULL)
                    {
                        resultp2->prev->data = carryon;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultp2->prev->data += carryon;
                    }
                }

                resultp2 = resultp2->prev;
            }






          /*  int* buffer;
            int lenBuffer = 0;
            void multiplyHelper(int v, node* , int o);
            void addToBuffer(int v, int i);
            node* multiply(node* num1, node* num2)
        {
            if (num1 == NULL || num2 == NULL) return NULL;

            int length1 = getSize(num1);
            int length2 = getSize(num2);
            if (length1 > length2) return multiply(num2, num1);

            // initialize buffer
            lenBuffer = length1 + length2;
            buffer = new int[lenBuffer];
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(int) * lenBuffer);

            // multiply
            int offset = 0;
            node* anode = num1;
            while (anode && anode->data!= -1)
            {
                multiplyHelper(anode->data, num2, offset);
                anode = anode->prev;
                offset++;
            }
            // transfer buffer to a linked list
            node* h;
            int pos = 0;

            while (pos < lenBuffer && buffer[pos] == 0) pos++;
            if (pos < lenBuffer)
            {

                node* temp;
                temp->data = buffer[pos++];
                h = temp;

                anode = h;
                while (pos < lenBuffer)
                {
                    node* temp;
                    temp->data = buffer[pos++];
                    anode->prev = temp;
                    anode = anode->prev;
                }
            }
            delete buffer;
            lenBuffer = 0;
            buffer = NULL;
            cout << h->data << endl;
            return h;
        }

        // multiply a single digit with a number
        // called by multiply()
        void multiplyHelper(int value, node* head, int offset)
        {
           // assert(value >= 0 && value <= 9 && head != NULL);
            if (value == 0) return;

            node* anode = head;
            int pos = 0;
            while (anode != NULL)
            {
                int temp = value * anode->data;
                int ones = temp % 10;
                if (ones != 0) addToBuffer(ones, offset + pos + 1);
                int tens = temp / 10;
                if (tens != 0) addToBuffer(tens, offset + pos);

                anode = anode->prev;
                cout << anode->data;
                pos++;
            }

        }

        // add a single digit to the buffer at place of index
        // called by multiplyHelper()
        void addToBuffer(int value, int index)
        {
         //   assert(value >= 0 && value <= 9);
            while (value > 0 && index >= 0)
            {
                int temp = buffer[index] + value;
                buffer[index] = temp % 10;
                value = temp / 10;
                index--;
            }
        }*/


// Driver program to test above functions
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char filename[50];
        string name= argv[1];
        string dig;
        name.erase(0,9);//Parse input to only get input file.
        ifstream file;
        int digits;
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++){
            if(name.at(i) == ';'){
          //      dig = name.substr(0,name.length()-i);
                name = name.substr(0,name.length()-i);
            }
        }
        //cout << dig << endl;
        //file.open("input.txt");
        file.open(name.c_str());
        digits = 2;
        ///////



        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int words = 0;
        int numbers = 0;
        while(!file.eof()) //Goes through whole file until no more entries to input
            {
                string word;
                getline(file,word); //Inputs next element as a string
//                word << file;
                //cout << word << '\n';
                int x = 0;
                node *head1 = NULL, *head2 = NULL, *result = NULL;
                int counter = 0;
                int t1index = 0; //keep tracks of nodes to multiply
                int t2index = 0;
                char operatorX;
                LinkedList tempList1;
                LinkedList tempList2;
                while(x<word.length()) //Loops through each string input
                {
                    //if(x<word.length()&&isalpha(word.at(x))) //Checks that x is in bounds and that char at position x is a letter
                    if(x<word.length()&&isdigit(word.at(x))) //Checks that x is in bounds and that char at position x is a number/digit
                    {
                        int start = x;
                        while(x<word.length()&&isdigit(word.at(x))) //Loops past the number portion
                        {
                            x++;
                        }
                        string temp = word.substr(start, x).c_str();
                     //   cout << temp << '\n';
                          for(int i = 0; i < temp.length();i++){
                            tempList1.addValue(atoi(temp.substr(i, 1).c_str()));
                          //  push(&head1, atoi(temp.substr(i, 1).c_str()));
                            counter++;
                            t1index++;
                          }
                          //search for the operator
                          while(x<word.length()){
                                    if(x<word.length()&& (!isspace(word.at(x)) && !isdigit(word.at(x))))
                                    {
                                    while(x<word.length()&&(!isspace(word.at(x)) && !isdigit(word.at(x)))) //Loops past the letter portion
                                    {
                                       // cout << (word.at(x))<< '\n';
                                        operatorX = word.at(x);
                                        x++;
                                    }
                                        //search second value
                                         while(x<word.length()){ //second value find
                                            //start
                                               if(x<word.length()&&isdigit(word.at(x))) //Checks that x is in bounds and that char at position x is a number/digit
                                                    {
                                                        int start = x;
                                                        while(x<word.length()&&isdigit(word.at(x))) //Loops past the number portion
                                                        {
                                                            x++;
                                                        }
                                                        string temp = word.substr(start, x).c_str();

                                                          for(int i = 0; i < temp.length();i++){
                                                            tempList2.addValue(atoi(temp.substr(i, 1).c_str()));
                                                        //    push(&head2, atoi(temp.substr(i, 1).c_str()));
                                                      //      cout << atoi(temp.substr(i, 1).c_str());
                                                            counter++;
                                                          }
                                                           //////START READING NUMBERS BACKWARDS
                                                             LinkedList finalList;
                                                            node* tempA = tempList1.tail;
                                                            node* tempB = tempList2.tail;
                                                        //    multiply(tempA, tempB);
                                                                    //ADDITION
                                                                    while(tempA != NULL){
                                                                        if(tempA->data != -1){
                                                                            push(&head1,tempA->data);
                                                                      //      cout << tempA->data;
                                                                        }
                                                                        tempA = tempA->prev;

                                                                    }
                                                                    while(tempB != NULL){
                                                                        if(tempB->data != -1){
                                                                            push(&head2, tempB->data);
                                                                     //      cout << tempB->data;
                                                                        }
                                                                        tempB = tempB->prev;

                                                                    }

                                                               //         multiply(head1, head2);
                                                             //       result = multiply(head1, head2);


                                                      //          tempList1.PrintReverse();
                                                           addList(head1, head2, &result);
                                                            printList(head1);
                                                            cout << operatorX;
                                                            printList(head2);
                                                            cout << "=";
                                                            printList(result);
                                                            cout << endl;

                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        x++;
                                                    }
                                            //end
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        x++;
                                    }
                                    }
                    }
                    else //If char at position x is neither number or letter skip over it
                    {
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            }






}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working in C++, use a template/overloaded operators. Cast your `int`s to a floating point type as necessary. See e.g.:
[C++ Template problem adding two data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030697/c-template-problem-adding-two-data-types)

Comment: Ah I think I wasn't clear in the original post.

Right now it works with whole numbers eg.

53020184+492881

but I need it to work with decimal numbers as well eg.

53.019283 + 49.2717181

Comment: No, you were clear enough — its just all your code is explicitly typed `int`. You need something like a `double` to handle decimal numbers. Templates (with which you can handle multiple types) is basically the whole raison d'être of C++ as a language. Your code is sufficiently advanced that you should know/be able to do this at this point.

Comment: Got it, I changed the stuff to double, but the problem I'm running into now is that when I store the number into the linked lists I lose the decimal since the list only stores the numbers and I can't figure out how to make sure I put the decimal back in when I'm through with adding the numbers

Comment: Not 100% sure without seeing your new code, but the types you are using in your list *should* retain their type. Maybe see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19484515/2351351