# Integer promotion, C++ and templates

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, templates, gcc, c++11

C defines various rules regarding integer promotion, here's a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe/50632#50632) describing how this works.

In GCC you can do this:

```
#define max(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Which will evaluate to the maximum value of the type determined by the C rules as above.

In using `std::min` or `std::max` using mixed types, it's necessary to provide the appropriate type to cast to as a template parameter:

```
size_t const subcount = std::min<Offset>(count, treecap - offset);
```

To get a min/max that evaluates to the type as per the C integer promotion rules, it would be necessary to know how the types relate, and what the resultant type would be, for every combination of left and right input types.

I wish to perform a min/max, with the same behaviour as the C sample under GCC given above, and with the same promotion (thereby ensuring the same behaviour as in GCC). How can I do this in C++ and/or MSVC?

Note that immediately after performing this "natural" min/max, I'll be `numeric_cast`ing to the expected size range.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [a `promote` template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426330/uses-of-a-c-arithmetic-promotion-header/2450157#2450157)?

Comment: @James McNellis: Yes something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very good implementation here that I've used for various projects: http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/traits.html

Comment: A shame this isn't part of standard C++, but it hardly surprises me. C++ can't make its mind up about compatbility with C and lives in a nasty no mans land.