# C++ Function Template With Flexible Return Type

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say that we have a function like so

```
template <class T, class T2>
T getMin(T a, T2 b) {
  if(a < b)
    return a;
  return b;
}
```

if we call the function like so

```
int a, b;
long c;

a = getMin(b, c);
```

if c is < a, then the value of c will be type casted to int.

Is it possible to make the return type flexible so that it would return an int, or long, or any other type considered smaller by "<" without being type casted?

edit :
the type involved in the function can be anything from simple type to complex classes where typecasting sometime won't be possible.

Comment: @Prasoon: I hope you undelete your answer, since it is correct.  Even if `(a > b)? a: b` cannot be evaluated at compile time, it still has a type.  Declaring a local variable with `auto x = (a > b)? a: b;` is valid and therefore so is using `decltype`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++0x will allow you to use the `auto` keyword in order to let the compiler derive the return time of an expression.

---

For C++03 the only way I found to automatize such process is to define a template class `Promotion` that defines the strongest type between two types, and then specialize it for any couple of types you might need to use.

```
template<> class Promotion< long, int > { typedef long strongest; }
template<> class Promotion< int, long > { typedef long strongest; }
```

and thus:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2 >
Promotion<T1,T2>::strongest function( const T1 &a, const T2 &b ) { ... }
```

If you choose to try this solution, I'd suggest to generate the Promotion specializations with an automatically generated header file.

---

Edit: I reread the question after reading the other (now deleted) answer:

You can't return the type of the smaller variable. That's because the value of the variables will only be found out at runtime, while your function return type must be defined at compile time.

The solution I proposed will return always the strongest type between the two variables' type.

Comment: No, but decltype makes finding the stronger type really easy.  For example, `getMin(T a, T2 b) -> decltype(a | b)`.  Then manually writing zillions of specializations is not necessary.

Comment: Indeed, but `auto` + `decltype` are not C++03 standard.

Comment: This could work, but only when the type involved in the equation is simple type. by returning the strongest type between both, we avoid losing precision, but we still don't get the actual type.

Comment: As I added with the Edit, a function cannot return a runtime-chosen type. The function must have its return type statically defined at compile time. If it's mandatory for you to get the actual type you can't use a function, a macro would do it, instead. Another solution could be that of returning two values, a `T` and a `T2` object (eg: in a tuple) plus another value to specify which is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, you want to take the type that is more generic. Like, `int` and `double` should become `double`; `char*` and `string` should become `string`. This works with my [`promote<>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426330/uses-of-a-c-arithmetic-promotion-header/2450157#2450157) template. Just write

```
template <class T1, class T2>
typename promote<T1, T2>::type getMin(T1 const& a, T2 const& b) {
  if(a < b)
    return a;
  return b;
}
```

This will always return a copy, even if `T1` and `T2` is the same type (like `string`), which is why I would overload it for non-const same-type arguments

```
template <class T>
T &getMin(T &a, T &b) {
  if(a < b)
    return a;
  return b;
}
```

These two variants seem to be a reasonable configuration. If you want to have a slightly more risky, but in more cases performant, solution, you can accept `T const&`, also accepting temporaries. If you then use it like `getMin(a + b, b + c)`, which could pass temporaries, and use the result directly, that's all fine. The result is usable and can still be copied into a local variable.

Comment: Does this compile anywhere? After all, Andrei complained that no current compiler accepted the solution – but admittedly that was several years ago.

Comment: @Konrad dunno what his solution was. But from what I remember, he tried to catch more cases with the "getMin" lvalue-returning version.

Comment: I mean this seminal work: http://www.drdobbs.com/184403774 … and I just realized that it’s from 2001 so the relevant paragraph (“there's a little detail worth mentioning. Sadly, Min doesn't work with any compiler I have access to. In fairness, each compiler chokes on a different piece of code.”) is probably obsolete.