# changeble "return type template" by parameter type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, return-type, typename

I'm studying template functions and searching, trying to make it work for some hours but i cannot find out.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename A, typename B, typename C>
C add (A a, B b){
  return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    float y = 2.5;
    float z = add(x,y);
    cout << "z is: " << z ;

return 0;
}
```

Another solution I found is

```
template <type name A, typename B>
auto add(A a, B b){
     return a + b;
}

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    float y = 2.5;
    cout << add(x,y);
}
```

Second code works fine, The return types changes automatically whatever parameter type I set. However, when I put one more `<typename C>` for the add function for the return type, it says error message. How can I make it run in the main function ?

Comment: For the 1st code you need to specify the template argument explicitly, like `float z = add<int, float, float>(x,y);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Function Template With Flexible Return Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530756/c-function-template-with-flexible-return-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default return template parameter defined through `std::declval()` and `decltype()`.

The following is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename A, typename B,
          typename C = decltype(std::declval<A>() + std::declval<B>())>
C add (A a, B b)
 { return a + b; }

int main()
 {
   int x = 1;
   float y = 2.5;
   float z = add(x,y);

   std::cout << "z is: " << z << std::endl;
 }
```

This works also with C++11 when the `auto` return type (without the `-> decltype()`) is valid starting from C++14.

Comment: You could also use C++11 trailing return type, should be much shorter than those `delcval()`s.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - do you mean `auto add (A a, B b) -> delctype(a+b)`? This works in C++11 also but the OP ask for a template `typename C` added for return type.