# How can this return type be determined at compile-time?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this “min” template of cpp-next at fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195150/why-is-this-min-template-of-cpp-next-at-fault)

From another question I got this function template:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto min(T x, U y) -> decltype(x < y ? x : y) {
    return x < y ? x : y;
}
```

It compiles and seems to work fine, but I'm unsure why it works. How can the return type be deduced at compile-time? — I would think it can be either `T` or `U` depending on which argument is smaller, and that can only be determined at run-time.

Comment: Your "question" could be a comment to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195150/why-is-this-min-template-of-cpp-next-at-fault

Comment: @FailedDev Why isn't it good as a question on its own? My question is about how it works, that seems to be about subtle mistakes in the implementation of the function. Quite different...

Comment: The type of the expression `x < y ? x : y` is not dependent on the values of `x` and `y`, only on their types. The rules for this are spelled out in section 5.16 (Conditional operator), but the short version is that the compiler looks for a common type that both `x` and `y` can be converted to.

Comment: @Paul, downvoting my (5) questions will not get you anywhere. In addition the system detects such biased downvotes automatically and corrects them. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression of the form `a ? b : c` always returns the same type whether `a` is true-valued or not. If `b` and `c` are of different types, then type promotion occurs, just like when `3 + 4.2` evaluates to `7.2` (via `double(3) + 4.2`).