# Expressing the result type of the ternary conditional `?:`

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

What do you specify the return type to be for the following function which should act like `?:` but without the laziness?

My first attempt was the following:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 myif(bool b, T1&& true_result, T2&& false_result)
{
    if (b) {
        return true_result;
    } else {
        return false_result;
    }
}
```

But then I found given:

```
int f() { return 42; }
int x = 5;
```

whilst

```
(true ? x : f())++;
```

falls to compile,

```
myif(true, x, f())++;
```

compiles fine and returns a dangling reference.

My second attempt was to change the return type to:

```
typename std::remove_reference<T1>::type
```

but then

```
(true ? x : x)++
```

works, but:

```
myif(true, x, x)++
```

does not as I'm returning by value now.

Even:

```
auto myif(bool b, T1&& true_result, T2&& false_result) 
  -> typeof(b ? true_result : false_result)
```

fails, I'm not sure why, perhaps `typeof` converts it's argument to a value type. In any case the point was to express the type explicitly, not through `auto` and `typeof`.

Any idea how to make a function that returns the same type as `?:`?

Comment: `std::common_type`, but that doesn't preserve value categories since the result is `std::decay`'d. Also, the C++11 spelling is `decltype`, not `typeof`.

Comment: Why not `decltype(b ? std::forward<T1>(true_result) : std::forward<T2>(false_result))`?

Comment: Anyway, the rules for `?:` occupies 1.5 pages of the standard. Some parts of it requires knowing things that is AFAIK impossible to determine programmatically (e.g., whether an expression can be converted to `T&` or `T&&` *subject to the constraint that the reference must bind directly*); others are possible but extremely tedious to implement without `decltype` (e.g., the usual arithmetic conversions).

Comment: If you need C++03 compatibility, you may wanna lookup this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450157/34509 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way is what [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349438/expressing-the-result-type-of-the-ternary-conditional#comment45043005_28349438) proposed:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> 
auto myif(bool b, T1&& true_result, T2&& false_result)
    -> decltype(b ? std::forward<T1>(true_result) : std::forward<T2>(false_result))
{
    if (b) {
        return true_result;
    } else {
        return false_result;
    }   
}
```

Which, in C++14, becomes just:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> 
decltype(auto) myif(bool b, T1&& true_result, T2&& false_result)
{
    // same body
}
```

Given that:

```
int f() { return 42; }
int x = 5, y = 7;

myif(true, x, f())++; // error: lvalue required as increment operand
myif(false, x, y)++;  // OK
```

Comment: Does that ever actually compile if the types are different? the bool isn't a compile time constant, so how can the compiler know what type the result should be, unless they're the same type to begin with...?

Comment: @user673679 Yeah of course. As long as there's a common type (you can't do like `b ? "hello" : 4.2` for instance). See [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) for a longer explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I hadn't really thought about the ternary operator like that before.

Comment: Your C++14 version is broken.  "If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder type has multiple return statements, the return type is deduced for each return statement.  If the type deduced is not the same in each deduction, the program is ill-formed."

Comment: Both versions are broken if the types are the same. If `T1` and `T2` are both `int`, then in the C++11 version, the return type gets declared as `int &&`. In the C++14 version, `decltype(auto)` causes the return type to be deduced as `int &&`. Either way, both `true_result` and `false_result` are lvalues which cannot bind to an rvalue reference.